# Need number that displays date to change when date changes?

Tags: iphone, xcode, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I need to create a loop that detects when 24 hours passes, the number changes on my calendar from 1 to 2 then 2 to 3 ... all the way to 31. So when it is the 31 it says 31. However the number is on my tab-bar symbol and I have drawn the number on using quartz and so the number is not an integer but an nsstring with the number written. the number that is displayed is 6 when it should be today's date 17. Not sure where i am going wrong?

Here is my code so far:

```
- (void)updateLabelForDate:(NSDate *)date {
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
NSInteger days = timeInterval / (60*60*24);
NSArray *sloganArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        NSLocalizedString(@"1", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"2", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"3", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"4", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"5", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"6", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"7", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"8", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"9", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"10", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"11", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"12", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"13", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"14", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"15", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"16", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"17", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"18", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"19", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"20", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"21", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"22", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"23", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"24", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"25", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"26", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"27", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"28", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"29", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"30", nil),
                        NSLocalizedString(@"31", nil),
                        nil];
NSInteger usedSloganIndex = (int)days % [sloganArray count];
slogan = [sloganArray objectAtIndex:usedSloganIndex];
NSLog(@"Slogan: %@", slogan);
NSLog(@"%i",usedSloganIndex);

int x,y,width,height;


x = 23;
y = 440;
width = 20;
height = 20;



CustomBadge *customBadge1 = [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:slogan];


- (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application {
[self updateLabelForDate:[NSDate date]];
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
[self updateLabelForDate:[NSDate date]];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Override point for customization after application launch.

// Add the tab bar controller's view to the window and display.
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[self addTabBarArrow];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

[self updateLabelForDate:[NSDate date]];

return YES;
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be notified when the date changes by implementing `applicationSignificantTimeChange:` in your application delegate. Check [its documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for when it will be called, but it includes the times you almost certainly want.

Comment: If you want today's date, you get that using `NSDateComponents`. The math you've done is nothing similar to the current date. You've divided the number of seconds by the number of seconds in a day, and then taken the modulo 31 of that. That number has no relationship to a meaningful Gregorian date. That's not even the average number of days in a month.